# Pitch Period & Fundamental Frequency of Soundwave in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have just recorded a tiny section of audio in MatLab using the `>> x = wavrecord( 2*fs, fs, ‘double’);` command.

So far I have figured out how to playback the audio using `soundsc(x, fs);` and to plot to a graph using `plot(x)`.

Here is a zoomed in screen capture of my wave:

[image]

Does the x-axis display the duration in milliseconds and the y-axis display the amplitude?
I think I may have switched off the axis names by accident.

I need to confirm this before i try to calculate the Fundamental Period and Fundamental Frequency of the wave.

If I've guessed my axis correct, am I right in thinking the fundamental period is the amount of time it takes for one periodic wave to repeat itself, making it `(T)`? So in this case approximately `0.0050 seconds`?

And, the fundamental frequency is `f0 = 1/T = 1/0.0050`?

I have been playing around all day and reading so much. I hope i havent confused myself and just embarrassed myself on this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x-axis is just sample number. This would go from 1 to the number of samples your sound recording contains. The sample time which is the time period between two samples is 1/fs. fs is your sampling frequency. So the time period for 50 samples would be 50/fs.

For most waveforms you cannot find Fundamental period easily by looking at it. As @duffymo mentions you need to compute FFT or PSD and then find the location of your first peak which is not DC. This would be your fundamental frequency.

Answer (score 1):

This time trace looks pretty noise to me.  It's not "frequency"; it's "frequencies".

If you do an FFT on this, you'll find that there are lots of frequencies involved.  You may be able to reproduce the main signal with a smaller number of harmonics, but I doubt that it'll be just one.